# Get the groups of a user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ldap, openldap

I'm developping an application using spring-boot. I use Ldaptemplate API to communicate with Ldap repository. I need to retrieve user details and groups included (membreOf). This is a snippet of my code:

```
public Person findCustomerByUid(String uid, String orgUnit) throws InvalidNameException {

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setUid(uid);
        p.setOu(orgUnit);
        Name dn = buildDn(p);
        return (Person) ldapTemplate.lookup(dn, new PersonContextMapper());
    } 

private static class PersonContextMapper implements ContextMapper<Object> {
        public Object mapFromContext(Object ctx) {
            DirContextAdapter context = (DirContextAdapter) ctx;
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setFirstName(context.getStringAttribute("cn"));
            p.setLastName(context.getStringAttribute("sn"));
            p.setOu(context.getStringAttribute("ou"));
            p.setEmail(context.getStringAttribute("mail"));
            p.setUid(context.getStringAttribute("uid"));
            p.setIdEventuate(context.getStringAttribute("title"));
            //            p.setLstRoles(context.getStringAttributes("roleNames"));  // Doesn't work
            return p;
        }
    }
```

This work but the list of roles is always null. 
I tried this but without succes:

```
Object[] o1 = context.getObjectAttributes("memberOf");  // doesn't work
```

Would you have any ideas ?

This is a screenshot of a user usring Apache directory:

[image]

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It depends on several things:

1. *If* you have the `memberof` overlay configured *and* the users were added to their groups *after* `memberof` was configured, `memberOf` will work. If it doesn't, one of those conditions isn't true. In particular, `memberof` isn't retrospective.
2. If those conditions don't or can't hold, you will need to conduct a subtree search starting from the `groups` subtree, using a filter like `uniqueMember={0}` where the parameter is provided as the DN of the user.

Comment: Thanks @EJP, how I can configure `memberof` ? I modified my question, I added a screenshot of a user using Apache directory. As you can see in the screenshot the attribute `memberof` is present

Comment: Ah well in that case you need to configure the lookup operation to return the operational attributes as well. The normal attributes are returned by default, or by specifying the pseudo-attribute `*`, and the operational attributes like `memberOf` by specifying `+`.

Comment: Exactly because that operational attributes are not returned  by default, The configuration is Ldap side or JAVA side ?

Comment: Java/Spring side. I know exactly nothing about the Spring interface to LDAP but that's where it is.